# getting label text in gridview

Tags: .net, winforms, gridview

I want to get cell value from gridview,but empty string is returned .I am implemented
    code in selectedindexchanged event of radiobuttonlist .I iterate through gridview
    and access cell by code .but problem is stll remaining.I used three itemtemplate ,each
    has one elemnt so that each element get its own coulmn .aspx

```
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >



               <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <itemtemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("qno") %>'>

           </asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>

          <asp:TemplateField>

          <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("description") 
        %>'>

          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <itemtemplate>
          <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
           runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="changed"  AutoPostBack="true" >


             <asp:ListItem   Value="agree" Selected="True" >

             </asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem 
                Value="disagree">

             </asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="strongagree">

             </asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="strondisagree">

             </asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </itemtemplate>
    </templatefield>
                </Columns>

           </asp:GridView>

         <asp:Label ID="Labe11" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
        Code behind: public void changed(object sender, EventArgs e) {

              for(int i=0;i<GridView2.Rows.Count;i++)
              {
                  string labtext;
                    RadioButtonList list = 
            GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("RadioButtonList1") as RadioButtonList;
                   labtext= GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;


                   Label1.Text = labtext;


              }



                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included all the HTML from the .aspx page above? What you have there is not going to work.  ItemTemplates do not form columns, they are included *within* TemplateField columns.

Example (adapted from your code, 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.itemtemplate.aspx
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Runat="server" 
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("description") %>'>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Choice">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="changed"  AutoPostBack="true" >
                    <asp:ListItem Value="agree" Selected="True" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="disagree" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="strongagree" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="strondisagree" />
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You'll need a separate TemplateField definition for each column.

Comment: i have used separate <templetfield >but problem is still

Answer (score 0):

Please try this instead:

```
GridView2.Rows[i].FindControl("RadioButtonList1") as RadioButtonList;
```

Regards,
Sivakumar